# Force Calloc to return Null for unit testing

Tags: c

I have a code for which I have to write a unit test for. The statement has a `calloc()` in it. I have to verify the False condition where the `calloc()` returns Null. I am sure that I would always have the required memory available. Is there a way I can make `calloc()` return null?

Comment: @JazzCat  Can you be more specific as to the part of the question which caused you trouble? I found it logical and esasy to understand.

Comment: Pass second argument as `0` to `calloc`. It will return `NULL`.

Comment: @haccks That's implementation-defined

Answer (score 4):

You can ask `calloc()` with a very large amount of memory, probably larger then what your system can provide.

If it doesn't still return `NULL`, then repeat it few times. You will get what you desire.

Comment: Another way would be to patch in a substitute function that does return `NULL`, if the object is to check that the calling function behaves gracefully.

Comment: Your first statement is funny but really answers the question :)

Comment: Interesting. I was about to write "you can allocate more memory than you think" (cf. https://scvalex.net/posts/6/ or such), but that may not be true for calloc which probably touches every page.

Comment: @haccks, :D Simple solutions are funny sometimes.

Comment: @haccks : but then again, [this strategy may not work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19750796/2564301). Oh wait, Peter A. Schneider mentions it needs zeroing out. ...good point, actually. Then I Don't Know.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, I first thought about `ptrace()` and intentionally failing it, but then thats complicated.

Comment: @DevSolar True. It would fail only when the last (available) page is actually hogged by the process. (But you may be able to fiddle with resource limits.)

Comment: @RadLexus; I am not sure about `calloc`.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the amount of memory allocated (because that would mean to change the code under test), you can certainly substitute your own `calloc()`. Just implement one which returns NULL and make sure the respective object file appears in the link command. If I'm not mistaken, the linker will only link to symbols from the standard library which are unresolved at that point. (I just see that this is Weather Vane's suggestion from the comments.)

If the memory allocation in the code to test is large compared to the memory the program uses elsewhere you may be able to test it by artificially limiting the program's allowed memory usage, probably by [calling `ulimit` in the calling shell with appropriate parameters.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process)

Comment: Re the edit: the substitute function could control that by calling the proper function and keeping track of amount of memory allocated.

Comment: @WeatherVane You mean if we know the exact number of bytes the code tries to allocate, and fail for that specific amount? Or possibly the nth call... I imagine that linking becomes more complicated. Well, one can probably change the function name through a compiler-submitted `define` when compiling the code under test.

Comment: Well, yes (and for other types of `malloc`). Suppose a 2-D dynamic array is being allocated. The UUT must behave nicely when it runs out of memory part way through the operation. For many applications, throwing one's hands in the air and calling `exit()` is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to, in the unit test, write a function that has the same signature as `calloc()`,

Then wrap the call to `calloc()` in your unit test, with something like:

```
#ifdef CALLOC
...your calloc function
#endif
```

Then compile with `-DCALLOC` to have the unit test use your `calloc()`

Compile with out the (above) parameter to have the unit test use the system version of `calloc()`

Then when testing with your version of `calloc()` it can return NULL to test the failure path

In general, unit tests should be run via a script, so it should be very repeatable to run the specific unit test more than once, say once with the system `calloc()` and once with the 'special' version of `calloc()`

Note this is a common method of getting system functions to return specific values when performing unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Most trivial approach:

```
#define calloc(what, ever) NULL
```