Discrepancy Between jemalloc memory stats and htop
My C++ application is using jemalloc as a memory allocator. Jemalloc exposes a stats API using which I can fetch different metrics like stats.active etc.
I have a server where the memory used value indicated by htop is smaller than the stats.active and stats.allocated values reported by jemalloc stats API. htop says that the memory used is 2.79 GB but stats.active reports it as 4.13 GB. All other stats values like stats.allocated are well above 4 GB as well.
What would explain such a huge discrepancy?

Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750796/allocating-more-memory-than-there-exists-using-malloc. When jemalloc returns non-NULL there is no guarantee that the memory really is reserved.
